# How to mock a state value in jest

Tags: react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-native-testing-library

A react native 0.70 component displays `items` in `FlatList`. The array `items` is a state and is assigned value in hook `useEffect`. I would like to jest (0.29) it to see if a item's name is shown up on screen so a mock of state `items` is needed. Here is the render item code for `FlatList`:

```
 return (
      <TouchableOpacity testID={'listselltrade.detail'} onPress={() => {item.sell ? navigation.navigate("Deal Detail", {item:item}) : navigation.navigate("Trade Detail", item={item})} } >. <<== here is the testID
      <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:"row", alignItems:"center", width:wp("100%"), height:wp("17%")}}>
        
          <View style={{width:wp("17%"), padding:wp("0.1%")}}>
          {sourceUri && sourceAltUri ? <CachedImage source={{uri:sourceUri}} sourceAlt={{uri:sourceAltUri}} style={styles.itemImage} /> : null}
          </View>
          <View style={{width:wp("25%")}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:wp("4.2%"), flexWrap:"wrap"}}>{item.artwork.item_name}</Text> 
          </View>
          <View style={{width:wp("8%")}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:wp("4.2%"), flexWrap:"wrap"}}>{helper.returnStatus(item.status)}</Text> 
          </View>
          <View style={{width:wp("7%")}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:wp("4.2%"), flexWrap:"wrap"}}>{item.price+item.shipping_cost}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{width:wp("3%"),flexDirection:"row"}}>
            {item.sell ? <Icon name='logo-usd' size={_size}  /> : <Icon name='sync' size={_size} />}
          </View>
          <View style={{width:wp("8%")}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:wp("4.2%"), flexWrap:"wrap"}}>
                    {item.artwork.category.category_name}
            </Text>
          </View> 
          
          {item.sell && _me.id !== data.uploader_id && <View style={{width:wp("15%")}}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.push('ListBuyExg', {uploader_id:item.artwork.uploader_id, title:_sellerposter_name})} }>
                <Text style={{fontSize:wp("4.2%"), flexWrap:"wrap"}}>
                    {_sellerposter_name}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View> }
          {!item.sell && _me.id !== data.uploader_id && <View style={{width:wp("15%")}}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.push('ListBuyExg', {uploader_id:item.artwork.uploader_id, title:_sellerposter_name})} } >
                <Text style={{fontSize:wp("4.2%"), flexWrap:"wrap"}}>
                    {_sellerposter_name}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View> } 
          
          <View style={{width:wp("20%")}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:wp("3%"), flexWrap:"wrap"}}>{item.active_date.substring(0,10)}</Text>
          </View>
      </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
```

Here is jest code:

```
test ('has screen detail', async () => {

        
        const route = {params: {title:"my title", uploader_id:8}}; //8 is a test user. all is listed
        const navigation = {navigate:jest.fn()};
        const propsVal = {device_id:"a device id"};
        const authVal = {result:"fdkfjdsl;fjdsafkl", myself:{id:1,name:"me"}};
        const stateVal = {name:"me", alias:"akkus", aka:"aka"};
        const items = [{artwork:{item_name:"work name"}}];  //<<==mock state items
        const component = (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <propsContext.Provider value={propsVal}>
                    <authContext.Provider value={authVal}>
                        <stateContext.Provider value={stateVal}>
                            <ListSellTrade route={route} navigation={navigation}/>
                        </stateContext.Provider>
                    </authContext.Provider>
                </propsContext.Provider>              
           </NavigationContainer>);

        const wrapper = render(component);

        expect(screen.getByText('my title')).toBeTruthy(); //<<==pass
        expect(screen.getByText('work name')).toBeTruthy();  //<<==failed

        expect(screen.getByTestId('listselltrade.detail')).toBeTruthy();  //<<==failed

    })
```

But there is no `item` was rendered on screen and 2 expects were failed. What is the right way to mock state `items` so it can be fed into the jest for further test?

Comment: where `useEffect` gets data to set into `items`?

Answer (score 0):

You should start by using `screen.debug()` to output the host element tree your component is rendering. This should help you understand what actually gets rendered in your RNTL tests.

You might also want to consult official [RNTL + React Navigation example](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/blob/main/examples/react-navigation/README.md) how to properly test screen components when using React Navigation.